# Download a .xls file from a aspx page using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to download a .xls from this [Site](https://dinem.agroindustria.gob.ar/dinem_fob.fob_consultaproductos.aspx#)

I need to somehow click on the second button("Exporta informácion diária") on the grid and download the .xls file.

I tried with `requests` and `beautifulsoup` but didnt work.

After that, tried with `selenium` just for some tests and i managed to do what i needed.

Can someone please explain how can i download the .xls file without using a headless browser?

Thank You.

Comment: I would say RPA is the best solution for such problems. We are rapidly using RPA to download files from different portals. Defining workflow is very easy and minimal technical knowledge is required. Plus point - you can schedule the job as required.

Comment: I tried. But i'm missing something. So if i emulate the POST request, i can get the response and download the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you first need to understand what the flow of network requests that performs the download.
The easiest way is to open the developer tools in the browser you are using. And follow the appropriate requests.

In your case, there is an  POST Request, Which returns the exact address to the file.
Download it with a GET request.